# PHP field is truncated at the first space

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have an HTML form which writes two fields to a MySql database.  That part works fine.  Now I'm attempting to pre-fill two fields on the form with values from that database.  That way, when the screen is refreshed after the data is saved, or when the user displays the page on a subsequent visit, the field will be pre-populated with the value from the database.  One of the variable fields is $home_text.  I've temporarily echo'd the value of $home_text onto the page, and it displays all the words in the field.  However when I attempt to use $home_text in the Value clause of the Input, it truncates the field value after the first space.  How can I get the HTML form to display the entire value of $home_text without truncating at the first space?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="Form1" id="Form1" action="post_mess_age.php" method="post">
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myUser";
$password = "myPassword";
$dbname = "myDBName";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT notice from notification where page = 'home' limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (!$result) 
{
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
echo $row[0] . "<br>";

$home_text = $row[0];
echo 'Home_text is :' . $home_text . "<br>";

mysqli_close($conn);
?> 

<table class="table_800">
    <tr>
    <td width="480" align="left">
        <input type="text" size="80" maxlength="400" 
        name="home_page_text" id="home_page_text"
        value=<?php echo $home_text?>" 
        style="background-color:#FFC" />
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the value property is missing a double quote in your input, could that be the problem ?

```
value=<?php echo $home_text?>" 

value="<?php echo $home_text?>"
```

Comment: Yup.  That was it.  How did I miss that?  :-)  Many Thanks!